# Is it possible to save a PDF from an iOS app to the local directory in the iPad without webview?

Tags: javascript, ios, file, pdf, download

Every link seems to either use objective-c, which seems impossible to run unless you use webview. I used webview earlier today and it completely messed up the layout of the app. Can I download the PDF file to the app using JavaScript?

Comment: Do you mean from the application bundle to the document folder?

Comment: there are no directories on the ipad.

Comment: The pdf is stored locally on the app, basically its a description of how the project was made and the client wants a button on one of the pages which allows the user to download the pdf locally to the iPad (so they can access the PDF without running the app e.g. in iBook for example).